# Add slash at directories, remove slash at files - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I get this to work? I want one single trailing slash at directories, but no slashes at files. So `test.php/` becomes `test.php` and `test/folder` becomes `test/folder/`? Now I wrote this code, but that doesn't work:

```
# Remove trailing slash from files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)([.]{1})([^./]{1,})/$
RewriteRule . %1.%3 [R=301,L]

# Add trailing slash at directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/.]*)$
RewriteRule . %1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you talking about real folders or "fake" folders that are part of your rewriting scheme? Apache should automatically add a slash to real folders, unless instructed to do otherwise.

Comment: And also, why would you end up having a slash after file names??

Comment: No, the folders/files are virtual/fake, they do not really exists. And I meant removing trailing slashes at folders.